# Android navigation drawer array adapter

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-listview, android-fragments

I tried to add a edittext field to the navigation drawer using a linear layout as shown in the following code.

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@android:color/white" >

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/content_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
</FrameLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
    android:layout_width="320dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/EditText01"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:hint="Search" >
    </EditText>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/left_drawer_child"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp" />
</LinearLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

but when I'm trying to populate the list view it gives me a null pointer exception. Here is the code that I have used

```
DrawerLayout mDrawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
LinearLayout mDrawerLinear = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);
ListView mDrawerListChild = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer_child);
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.drawer_listview_item, drawerListViewItems);
mDrawer.closeDrawer(mDrawerLinear);
```

Error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

What I'm doing wrong here ?

Thank you!

Comment: You can either post more of your stacktrace or say where you get the NullPointerException... Might help a little to understand the problem. What is this `drawerListViewItems`, where do you initialize it?

Comment: see this http://hmkcode.com/android-creating-a-navigation-drawer/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

seems that your `String[] drawerListViewItems` is `null` when passing it to the `ArrayAdapter`.

define in your `strings.xml` a string-array with your content that should be displayed

```
...
<string-array name="planets_array">
        <item>Mercury</item>
        <item>Venus</item>
        <item>Earth</item>
        <item>Mars</item>
        <item>Jupiter</item>
        <item>Saturn</item>
        <item>Uranus</item>
        <item>Neptune</item>
</string-array> 
...
```

and fill your contentArray `drawerListViewItems` with this content from the `strings.xml` before passing it to the `ArrayAdapter`

```
...
String[] mPlanetTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.planets_array);
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.drawer_listview_item, mPlanetTitles );
...
```

sample taken from:
http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html#Init

Answer (score 0):

try this,

listView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, getResources().getStringArray(R.array.drawerItem)));